# Serilog Configuration Issue .net core 5, How to get serilog to use both appsettings.json and appsetting.development.json

Tags: configuration, serilog

This is my config in program.cs (.net core 5, Blazor app)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .CreateLogger();
            try
            {
                Log.Information("Application is Starting.");
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "The application failed to start.");                
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }            
        }
```

Which works ok if all settings used are appsettings.json, but how do I get this to use appsettings.development.json if the settings are different based on environment. Right now it is only reading the appsettings.json which makes sense as the AddJsonFile says appsettings.json, but is there a way to have it recognize appsettings.development.json also to overwrite settings per environment?

Comment: Believe I answered my own question .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json", optional: true) ... thanks to another post.

Comment: Another thing to note is that this solution does prevent Kestrel from logging on the command screen when running in your local dev environment but the other logs work.